# Jar cannot resolve dependencies copied in other folder

Tags: java, maven

**Solution (long story short):**

There were missing class path in pom.xml, so I need to add this entry (classpathPrefix):

```
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <classpathPrefix>${dependencies.path}</classpathPrefix>
                        <mainClass>com.xafero.strangectrl.App</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Class-Path>${dependencies.path}superloader-0.2.jar</Class-Path>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
```

**Question:**

I'm building my project with m2eclipse with command: *clean install package dependency:copy-dependencies*.

The problem is that I want to have all my dependency jars in folder **jars/**. To achive this I used **maven-dependency-plugin**:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory> ${project.build.directory}/jars </outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

My actual problem is that when I run my jar all dependencies cannot be resolved and i **jars/** folder I have libs that had **test** scope.

Full pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.xafero</groupId>
<artifactId>strangectrl</artifactId>
<version>1.1-alpha</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>strangectrl</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.jinput</groupId>
        <artifactId>jinput</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.xafero</groupId>
        <artifactId>superloader</artifactId>
        <version>0.2</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>${basedir}/lib_extra/superloader-0.2.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8</version>
        <type>jar</type>
        <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>15.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.easytesting</groupId>
        <artifactId>fest-assert</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>com.xafero.strangectrl.App</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                    <manifestEntries>
                        <Class-Path>superloader-0.2.jar</Class-Path>
                    </manifestEntries>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/jars</outputDirectory>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

@Jigar Joshi

I'm not sure is this that you want but here is my console output from eclipse (with -e)

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.xafero:strangectrl:jar:1.1-alpha
[WARNING] 'dependencies.dependency.systemPath' for com.xafero:superloader:jar should not point at files within the project directory, ${basedir}/lib_extra/superloader-0.2.jar will be unresolvable by dependent projects @ line 28, column 16
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin is missing. @ line 74, column 12
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin is missing. @ line 82, column 12
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING] 
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building strangectrl 1.1-alpha
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The artifact xstream:xstream:jar:1.2.2 has been relocated to com.thoughtworks.xstream:xstream:jar:1.2.2
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ strangectrl ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\MAG\git\StrangeCtrl\strangectrl\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ strangectrl ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ strangectrl ---
[INFO] Compiling 33 source files to C:\Users\MAG\git\StrangeCtrl\strangectrl\target\classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ strangectrl ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\MAG\git\StrangeCtrl\strangectrl\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ strangectrl ---
[INFO] Compiling 9 source files to C:\Users\MAG\git\StrangeCtrl\strangectrl\target\test-classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ strangectrl ---
[INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\Users\MAG\git\StrangeCtrl\strangectrl\target\surefire-reports

-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running com.xafero.strangectrl.cmd.InputUtilsTest
Tests run: 17, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.527 sec
Running com.xafero.strangectrl.input.ControllerPollerTest
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.412 sec
Running com.xafero.strangectrl.input.SimpleCallbackTest
Tests run: 15, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.049 sec
Running pl.grzeslowski.strangectrl.cmd.CommandFactoryTest
Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.057 sec
Running pl.grzeslowski.strangectrl.cmd.KeyCommandTest
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 sec
Running pl.grzeslowski.strangectrl.cmd.MouseCommandTest
Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 sec
Running pl.grzeslowski.strangectrl.cmd.MouseMoveCommandTest
Tests run: 3, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.023 sec
Running pl.grzeslowski.strangectrl.cmd.PovDirectionTest
Tests run: 5, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.002 sec
Running pl.grzeslowski.strangectrl.config.XStreamConfigLoaderTest
Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.221 sec

Results :

Tests run: 62, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:jar (default-jar) @ strangectrl ---
[INFO] Building jar: C:\Users\MAG\git\StrangeCtrl\strangectrl\target\strangectrl-1.1-alpha.jar
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3.1:install (default-install) @ strangectrl ---
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\MAG\git\StrangeCtrl\strangectrl\target\strangectrl-1.1-alpha.jar to C:\Users\MAG\.m2\repository\com\xafero\strangectrl\1.1-alpha\strangectrl-1.1-alpha.jar
[INFO] Installing C:\Users\MAG\git\StrangeCtrl\strangectrl\pom.xml to C:\Users\MAG\.m2\repository\com\xafero\strangectrl\1.1-alpha\strangectrl-1.1-alpha.pom
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ strangectrl ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 4 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) @ strangectrl ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ strangectrl ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\Users\MAG\git\StrangeCtrl\strangectrl\src\test\resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ strangectrl ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.10:test (default-test) @ strangectrl ---
[INFO] Skipping execution of surefire because it has already been run for this configuration
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.3.2:jar (default-jar) @ strangectrl ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.1:copy-dependencies (default-cli) @ strangectrl ---
[INFO] Copying guava-15.0.jar to C:\Users\MAG\git\StrangeCtrl\strangectrl\target\jars\guava-15.0.jar
[INFO] Copying xstream-1.2.2.jar to C:\Users\MAG\git\StrangeCtrl\strangectrl\target\jars\xstream-1.2.2.jar
[INFO] Copying superloader-0.2.jar to C:\Users\MAG\git\StrangeCtrl\strangectrl\target\jars\superloader-0.2.jar
[INFO] Copying junit-4.11.jar to C:\Users\MAG\git\StrangeCtrl\strangectrl\target\jars\junit-4.11.jar
[INFO] Copying log4j-1.2.14.jar to C:\Users\MAG\git\StrangeCtrl\strangectrl\target\jars\log4j-1.2.14.jar
[INFO] Copying jinput-2.0.5.jar to C:\Users\MAG\git\StrangeCtrl\strangectrl\target\jars\jinput-2.0.5.jar
[INFO] Copying jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-linux.jar to C:\Users\MAG\git\StrangeCtrl\strangectrl\target\jars\jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-linux.jar
[INFO] Copying jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-osx.jar to C:\Users\MAG\git\StrangeCtrl\strangectrl\target\jars\jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-osx.jar
[INFO] Copying jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar to C:\Users\MAG\git\StrangeCtrl\strangectrl\target\jars\jinput-platform-2.0.5-natives-windows.jar
[INFO] Copying jutils-1.0.0.jar to C:\Users\MAG\git\StrangeCtrl\strangectrl\target\jars\jutils-1.0.0.jar
[INFO] Copying fest-assert-1.4.jar to C:\Users\MAG\git\StrangeCtrl\strangectrl\target\jars\fest-assert-1.4.jar
[INFO] Copying fest-util-1.1.6.jar to C:\Users\MAG\git\StrangeCtrl\strangectrl\target\jars\fest-util-1.1.6.jar
[INFO] Copying hamcrest-core-1.3.jar to C:\Users\MAG\git\StrangeCtrl\strangectrl\target\jars\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
[INFO] Copying mockito-all-1.9.0.jar to C:\Users\MAG\git\StrangeCtrl\strangectrl\target\jars\mockito-all-1.9.0.jar
[INFO] Copying slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar to C:\Users\MAG\git\StrangeCtrl\strangectrl\target\jars\slf4j-api-1.5.8.jar
[INFO] Copying slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar to C:\Users\MAG\git\StrangeCtrl\strangectrl\target\jars\slf4j-log4j12-1.5.8.jar
[INFO] Copying xpp3_min-1.1.3.4.O.jar to C:\Users\MAG\git\StrangeCtrl\strangectrl\target\jars\xpp3_min-1.1.3.4.O.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 9.812s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Jan 26 20:06:05 CET 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 21M/173M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: could you please post stacktrace for your mvn build with `-e`

Comment: @MAGx2 ur build is SUCCESS then wht is the issue ?

Comment: When I run my jar I get 
D:\>java -jar C:\Users\MAG\git\StrangeCtrl\strangectrl\target\strangectrl-1.1-alpha.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/slf4j/LoggerFactory

Comment: so slf4j jar exist in the class path in run time ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are launching java by

```
java -jar C:\Users\MAG\git\StrangeCtrl\strangectrl\target\strangectrl-1.1-alpha.jar
```

so it doesn't have anything in your jars to classpath as you are assuming,

you would need `-cp C:\Users\MAG\git\StrangeCtrl\strangectrl\target\jars\*` set

Comment: This command java -cp C:\Users\MAG\git\StrangeCtrl\strangectrl\target\jars\* -jar C:\Users\MAG\git\StrangeCtrl\strangectrl\target\strangectrl-1.1-alpha.jar still produces error

Comment: @MAGx2 u run with C:\Users\MAG\git\StrangeCtrl\strangectrl\target\jars* or C:\Users\MAG\git\StrangeCtrl\strangectrl\target\jars\* ?

Comment: I think that the last \ disappears. The end is  target \ jars \ *

Comment: Is there anyway that my jar will automatically knows that in folder jars/ are jars that it need?

Comment: check frm which folder the classpath is picking the jars.You can place the jar thr too.

Comment: You could override Manifest.mf to include `Class-path:` http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html

Comment: @Jigar Joshi Thanks, adding to class path worked! The second problem is that maven exports jars with test scope, i.e. JUnit

Comment: You could filter those out by specifying excludeScope http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html